# NullPointerException while sending a push message from java to a flex client

Tags: java, apache-flex, push-notification, glassfish, blazeds

I'm not a native english, so sorry if my english is very bad ...

To explain my problem, I have a glassfish 3 server embedded in Eclipse for Java and I communicate with a Flex client via BlazeDS.

I've no problem to use my webservices, but I want to be able to notify something from my server to my client using push messages, and at this point, I have a problem.

I followed a lot of tutorials and here is my work :

```
public class TestServiceAdapter extends ServiceAdapter {

public TestServiceAdapter(){}


public Message createTestMessage(String message) {
    String objectToSend = new String(message);

    final AsyncMessage msg = new AsyncMessage();
    msg.setDestination("DataPush");
    msg.setClientId(UUIDUtils.createUUID());
    msg.setMessageId(UUIDUtils.createUUID());
    msg.setBody(objectToSend);
    return msg;
}

public void sendMessageToClients(Message msg) {
    ((MessageService) getDestination().getService()).pushMessageToClients(msg, false);
}

@Override
public Object invoke(Message message) {
    return null;
}
```

I've edited flex xml : messaging-config.xml :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<service id="message-service" 
    class="flex.messaging.services.MessageService">

    <adapters>
        <adapter-definition id="actionscript" class="flex.messaging.services.messaging.adapters.ActionScriptAdapter" default="true" />
        <adapter-definition id="TestServiceAdapter" class="utils.TestServiceAdapter"/>
        <!-- <adapter-definition id="jms" class="flex.messaging.services.messaging.adapters.JMSAdapter"/> -->
    </adapters>

    <default-channels>
        <channel ref="my-amf"/>
    </default-channels>

    <destination id="TestServiceAdapterDestination">
        <channels>
            <channel ref="my-streaming-amf"/>
        </channels>
        <adapter ref="TestServiceAdapter"/>
    </destination>

</service>
```

And here is my services-config.xml significant code :

```
<channels>
<channel-definition id="my-streaming-amf" class="mx.messaging.channels.StreamingAMFChannel">
    <endpoint url="http://{server.name}:{server.port}/{context.root}/messagebroker/streamingamf" class="flex.messaging.endpoints.StreamingAMFEndpoint"/>
    <properties>
         <!-- you don't need to set all these properties, this is just what we set, included for illustration, only -->
        <idle-timeout-minutes>0</idle-timeout-minutes>
        <max-streaming-clients>10</max-streaming-clients>
            <server-to-client-heartbeat-millis>5000</server-to-client-heartbeat-millis>
        <user-agent-settings>
            <user-agent match-on="Safari" kickstart-bytes="2048" max-streaming-connections-per-session="10"/>  
            <user-agent match-on="MSIE" kickstart-bytes="2048" max-streaming-connections-per-session="15"/> 
            <user-agent match-on="Firefox" kickstart-bytes="2048" max-streaming-connections-per-session="10"/>
        </user-agent-settings>
    </properties>
```

So my problem is that when I deploy my server and use that notification code I get a nullPointerException on :

```
((MessageService) getDestination().getService()).pushMessageToClients(msg, false);
```

The destination is never initialized from xml config.

I don't have a clue from what the problem could come. So I ask you for some help!

Answer (score 0):

The destination you are using (in your case "DataPush") in the java needs to be the same as the channel you set in the services config for your messaging service, which you have named "my-streaming-amf".
Either change the destination in java to be "my-streaming-amf", or rename the channel in the services config and messaging config to be "DataPush", e.g:

```
msg.setDestination("my-streaming-amf");
```

Cheers

Jacob.

Comment: Tried that this morning, didn't work, I still have that NullPointException on the getDestination() in sendMessageToClients().
How is the ServiceAdapter initialized ?

Answer (score 0):

Okey, I found out where I failed.

I thought that sending a notification via flex.messaging could be done without an active Thread, but that's not the case.

If you have the same problem :

```
 package utils;

    import flex.messaging.MessageBroker;
    import flex.messaging.messages.AsyncMessage;
    import flex.messaging.messages.Message;
    import flex.messaging.services.MessageService;
    import flex.messaging.services.ServiceAdapter;
    import flex.messaging.util.UUIDUtils;

    public class Notifier extends ServiceAdapter {
        private static DataSender thread;

        public void start() {
            if(thread==null) {
                thread= new DataSender();
                thread.start();
            }
        }
        public void stop() {
        thread.running = false;
        thread = null; }


    public static class DataSender extends Thread{
        public boolean running=true;
        private static boolean refreshBool = false;

        public static void notifyClients(){
            refreshBool = true;
        }

        public void run() {
            MessageBroker msgBroker = MessageBroker.getMessageBroker(null);
            String clientID = UUIDUtils.createUUID();
            while (running) {
                if(refreshBool){
                    refreshBool = false;
                    AsyncMessage msg = new AsyncMessage();
                    msg.setDestination("DataPush");
                    msg.setClientId(clientID);
                    msg.setMessageId(UUIDUtils.createUUID());
                    msg.setBody("Refresh");
                    msgBroker.routeMessageToService(msg, null);
                }
                }

            }
        }

        public Object invoke(Message message) {

            AsyncMessage newMessage = (AsyncMessage) message;
            newMessage.setBody("Refresh");
            MessageService msgService = (MessageService) getDestination().getService();
            msgService.pushMessageToClients(newMessage, false); 
        return null;    
    }
}
```

The messaging-config.xml and service-config.xml are nearly the same.

I think that's not an elegant solution, but that works, can be improved in the future.